# which of the clock is best to calculate the start-time endtime among CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Tags: c, linux

I want to calculate time elapsed by a particular function by getting starting time and ending time, then calculate the difference between them.

I am confused between the two clocks `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Which of these will give me the correct value of time in any unit (seconds, nanoseconds, or milliseconds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is the elapsed time since some undefined point of time in the past (for linux I believe this is boot time).

`CLOCK_REALTIME`, however, is essentially the computer's interpretation of the current real-world time. As a result, this time changes according to your computers internal clock; if you manually change your machine's time, `CLOCK_REALTIME` will change.

Thus, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is best for the task of finding elapsed time. Since it calculates the time elapsed since some arbitrary point in time, though, you will probably need to save the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` values at both the beginning and end of your function and subtract them to determine the elapsed time.